# knockout foreach server side

Tags: knockout.js

how can I client side for each when I've already server side for eached the elements?

There are double the elements after doing both.

Here's a fix using an old version of knockout by creating a binding handler that removes the child elements on init.  can anyone get this working with knockout 2.1?

http://jsfiddle.net/4f9N2/4/

```
var viewModel = {
    countries : [
        { name: 'UK' },
        { name: 'France' },
        { name: 'USA' }
    ]
}

ko.bindingHandlers.serverForEach = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // clear the list first
        $(element).children().remove();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) { 
        ko.bindingHandlers['template'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Um, why not just do it in one place -- either server-side or client-side?

Comment: I want server side for SEO and client side for changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `template` binding includes an `init` function that also needs to be called. Also you can simplify how you wrap the `template` handler functions.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverForEach = {
    init: function(element) {
        // clear the list first
        $(element).children().remove();
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.template.update
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/4f9N2/12/